# Enable service for specific user Only (UBUNTU)

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, systemd-unit

1. Currently writing a service unit file in Ubuntu, i want the service to be enabled for one user **UserA** only. The service will run automatically when UserA login but not for other users.
   How can I do this?

Below is my unit file placed in /etc/system

```
[Unit]
Description=Test unit

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo test > /home/UserA/sysdworking'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Is this a common practice? or all services should be system wide ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [systemd user](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) units. When you place your unit file in `~/.config/systemd/user`, systemd will automatically start your service when you login.

From the above link:

> As per default configuration in /etc/pam.d/system-login, the pam_systemd module automatically launches a systemd --user instance when the user logs in for the first time. This process will survive as long as there is some session for that user, and will be killed as soon as the last session for the user is closed. When #Automatic start-up of systemd user instances is enabled, the instance is started on boot and will not be killed. The systemd user instance is responsible for managing user services, which can be used to run daemons or automated tasks, with all the benefits of systemd, such as socket activation, timers, dependency system or strict process control via cgroups.

Comment: So, how can one enable #Automatic start-up of user instances?

Comment: With the following command: `loginctl enable-linger username`